# The argument type 'List<Set<ListBody>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ListBody'

Tags: flutter, dart

I take the first 5 groups of data returned from the `departures` API, using the class `Boards` and put them into a List of returned parsed `Json`.

```
   var mappedList = boards.departures!.take(5).toList();
```

I then map it so it is a recurring list, and choose the data's I want.

```
   var mappedValues = mappedList.map((m) => { 

     ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
   RichText (
              text: TextSpan( 
              children: <TextSpan> [
              TextSpan(text: "\n\nDestination ",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
               )
              ),
              TextSpan(text: m.transport!.headsign.toString(), style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontFamily: 'DMSans'
               )
              ),
              TextSpan(text: "\n\nNo.",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
               )
              ),
              TextSpan(text: m.transport!.name.toString(), style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontFamily: 'DMSans'
               )
              ),
              ]
              )
              )
              ])}).toList();
```

I then pass it to Metadata

```
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.setCustomValue("ListBody", ListBodyMetadata(mappedValues));
  
    mapMarker.metadata = metadata;
```

I have a Heading and then the data in each row.

I have tried different ways to use mapped data in a ListBody and I think this will work the best. I am just unable to pass it to Metadata as it is `List<Set<ListBody>>` instead of just the `ListBody` I need.

I have tried setting a Metadata class for `List<Set<ListBody>>` but it doesn't work as anticipated. ListBody works well within my application, I just need this dataset to pass into Metadata as one.

Any tips appreciated on how to pass the data, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks what you want is this?. Since then you have a ListBody with multiple text widgets instead of a list of ListBody( with 1 text widget)

```
var mappedValues = ListBody(
    children: mappedList.map((m) => RichText ()).toList(),
);
```

example on how to use RichText:

````
 RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'Hi, ',
                          style: style.onBackground(context, opacity: .7)),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: username,
                        style: style.onBackground(context),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks, am I right that the Text entry goes into the brackets following ```RichText```? When I put my ```text: TextSpan( children: <TextSpan> [ TextSpan...``` in it throws ```The argument type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>```

Comment: somewhat. I added an example on how to use `RichText`

Comment: Thank you, yeah thats the same format I had been using. The issue is when I enter that it all red underlines with the error ```The argument type 'Iterable<RichText>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.```

Comment: I think you're missing somewhere a toList(). Since RichText is a Widget, but you can't passt an Iterable to a List. Since List extends an Iterable

Comment: I set ```mappedList``` as ```.toList()``` as in the fist code example in my Q. Does it look right to you? Thanks

Comment: maybe do: `children: [...mappedList.map((m) => RichText ()).toList()]`. `...` is called spread operator and will insert each item just as you would if you write it with comma seperated

Comment: but yes it looks right to me